# Error getting balance for debit-credit-sdate,No data in MS ACCESS

Tags: java, sql, jsp, ms-access

Error getting balance for debit-credit-sdate

```
 <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Calendar" %>
    <%
    //java Code
    String date = (new java.util.Date()).toString();
    String UserName = request.getParameter("UserName");
    String CusId= request.getParameter("CusId");
    String AccountNo = request.getParameter("AccountNo");
    String Debit = request.getParameter("Debit");
    String Credit=request.getParameter("Credit");
    String Balance=request.getParameter("Balance");
    String sDate=request.getParameter("sDate");
    try
    {
    String s="jdbc:odbc:Database1";
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(s);
    Statement smt=conn.createStatement();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
    String sql= "SELECT  sDate, (SUM(Debit)*-1) + SUM(Credit)Balance FROM abcbank GROUP BY  sDate";
    ResultSet result = smt.executeQuery(sql);
    int count = 0;
    while (result.next())
    {
    result.getString(1,"Debit");
    result.getString(2,"Credit");
    result.getString(3,"Balance");
    result.getDate(4,startDate);

    }

    String update= "UPDATE abcbank SET Balance =Debit + Balance   WHERE AccountNo="+AccountNo+" ";
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(update);
    //statement.setString(1,"AccountNo");
    int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();
    if (rowsUpdated ==0)
    {
    out.println("This Emp does not Exists!");
    }
    else if(rowsUpdated ==1)
    {
    out.println("An existing user was updated successfully!");
    }
    conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
        %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Database is AccID- Username AccNo Debit Credit Balance sDate

How to getting balance for running account database for just like any Banking Passbook Type.

I'am trying to developed above code JSP Page however no error occurred whenever run but no data response in database and when I only updated account then each particular account[number of type sdatewise] is being updated

```
ano De. Cre.B.sadate 
56 100 0 100  12/09/2006
57 000 50 50  13/09/2006
56  00 60  40 14/09/2009
```

like this.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is here: `(SUM(Debit)*-1) + SUM(Credit)Balance`. It should be `SUM(Credit)-SUM(Debit) AS Balance` assuming Debit and Credit are always present, otherwise it should be `SUM(Nz(Credit,0))-SUM(Nz(Debit,0)) AS Balance`

Furthermore here:

```
 result.getString(1,"Debit");
 result.getString(2,"Credit");
 result.getString(3,"Balance");
 result.getDate(4,startDate);
```

That does not seem to actually do anything but maybe that's how it looks to me because I don't use jsp. But,

Your query only returns the fields: `sDate` and `Balance`. Change `SELECT sDate,` to `SELECT sDate AS startDate, SUM(Nz(Debit,0)) AS Debit, SUM(Nz(Credit,0)) AS Credit,`

`result.getDate(4,startDate);` should also probably be `result.getDate(4,"startDate");`

These are just the most obvious of problems; there may be more.

Comment: Hello, as per your suggestion i am implementing those,no achieve success,even if possible ,can you describe  and past edited properly to above entire JSP My Code.